# get frame of remote video in short time and set it as background of imageview

Tags: android, url, video, bitmap, performance

I want to display a frame from a remote video in an imageview
for that I am using this  code :

```
   Uri vidFile = Uri.parse(url);
        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                retriever.setDataSource(url,
                        new HashMap<String, String>());
            else
                retriever.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
        ;
        Bitmap b1 = retriever.getFrameAtTime();
```

but this code is very slow
I have to wait many secondes to show the frame of this video

can you give an alternatif of this knowing that I have to use it to get a frame of a lot of videos and put them in a list

Comment: will the retriever downloads the full file before returning?

Comment: no, if so then it will be more slow

Comment: how you resolve such issue..?